# Percona Server MongoDB on Linux - How to resolve installation conflict with mongodb-org?

Tags: linux, mongodb, yum, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

May I seek help, I am trying to install Percona Server for MongoDB on a linux machine.
However I am encountering this error.

The server has an existing mongodb and I am trying to install percona-server-mongodb via

```
sudo yum install percona-server-mongodb.version
```

But I am encountering

```
Error: percona-server-mongodb conflicts with mongodb-org-version.amzn1x86_64
```

What can I do to resolve this issue, should I uninstall the existing first? I wanted to know your opinion before I uninstall it because I am currently in uat-prod server because there is no test server to test it, but I already kept a backup of the databases and snapshots incase something goes wrong.

I am installing percona to do an encryption of database at rest by the way.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall conflicting packages.

If you are doing this in production, you should have backed up your data and *tested* the backup.